# Does Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit support the AMD Radeon HD 6790 video card?

Tags: ati, video, hardware, radeon

Quick question: Does Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04.1 64 bit support the AMD Radeon HD 6790 video card?

I tried checking Ubuntu's hardware support wiki information but it hasn't been updated since July 2011 - what a shame.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a HD 6970, so from the same 6000 series, and there is an AMD driver that can be installed in Ubuntu. You can download it from  "Software Sources" -> "Additional Drivers". Or you can download it and install manually from the [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx), which clearly specifies the 6900 series to have a supporting driver for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

No. AMD graphics cards are supported by AMD. Check if a [Linux driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) is available for Radeon HD 6790.

Comment: I think he's just wanting to know if there are drivers for the card available. There are closed source ones available under additional drivers.